# Attribute 'border' is considered outdated. VS2010?

Tags: xhtml, border

MY VS always prompt below messages.

1. Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): Attribute 'border' is considered outdated. A newer construct is recommended.
2. Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): Attribute 'link' is considered outdated. A newer construct is recommended.

What is the remedy for this?

Answer (score 0):

Stylesheets.

The CSS [`border` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/#border) and the CSS [`:link` peusdo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/#anchor-pseudo-classes). Both were standardised almost 20 years ago.

Comment: Still, why would the OP get this error with a transitional DOCTYPE? The whole purpose of transitional DOCTYPEs is so you can use those attributes if you want!

Comment: @MrLister — The error message isn't in the form of any validator that I know. Presumably it is throwing warnings and not clearly distinguishing them.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: I'm getting just that error message in Microsoft Expression Web 4. But the www.w3schools.com website has no complaints about using the border property. It just gives many examples of how to use it.

Probably the property was expected to be deprecated, but it never got there.